# Understanding of MVC ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, viewmodel

I am very new to this MVC environment and seems like having a ViewModel is a good practice, however, after all the findings on the internet, I don't quite understand how to apply ViewModel to my case.

I have a main table (**Customer**) with 3 columns: **Cust_ID**, **part_ID** and **dress_ID**.
 I'll have another table named **Body** which has two column: **part_ID** and **defaultValue**. 
I'll also have another table named **Dress** which has three column: **dress_ID**, **part_ID** and **LOV**

**Customer** table will store customer information with their prefered dress for each of the parts.
**Body** table will store the default value for each of the parts.
**Dress** table will store the list-of-value for the available dress for different parts.

In my view, I will have a number of dropdownlists depending on the data in **Body** table and display the corresponding list-of-value in the dropdownlists for my customer to choose. How should I actually design my solution by implementing viewmodel? Any help would be very much appreciated. 
Below showing my database sample data:

[image]

And My Expected View as below:
[image]

Comment: ViewModel is a class that provides data for your View, is the problem about LOVs (DropDownLists) or something else?

Comment: There isn't any problem if I'm to use ViewData to dump all the data into them and display at View. I need an advice on how to design my viewModel to achieve the same result

Comment: Well, I will put a simple solution as an answer, I hope it fulfill your expectation.

Answer (score 2):

A view model simply contains all the data your view needs.  That's it.  There's no special design, or magic involved.

If you have 10 form fields on your web page, you will have 10 properties in your View Model that are mapped to it.  You may also have things like hidden fields (such as Id's) or support data, such as collections for dropdownlists.

It's really a simple 1:1 mapping of your view's requirements to a class to allow your view to be strongly typed.

In your controller, you map between your data model and your view model in some way.  You might use a framework such as AutoMapper to do this, or you may just write custom code to do this mapping.  In any event, you simply copy whatever data is needed by the view from the data model on GET, and on POST you will map the results back to your data model and save changes.

Your view model may look very much (or even identical) to your data model, and it may seem like extra work to do this twice, and it is.. but keeping your view model separate pays off down the road when you need to make changes.  It may also help you to prevent certain security problems from occurring.

How you structure your View Model will depend on how you want to consume the data.  You may simply flatten your data model, and take several tables and turn them into one class.  Or you may create a set of objects that are iterated over in your view.  This all depends on what you want to do.

The concept of a view model is really very simple, and I think you are over thinking it.  It's just data that the view needs.  That's all.  And it has nothing to do with your data model, unless it just so happens to also look like it.

Comment: It means in order to achieve the expected view as stated above, I will only need to have a ViewModel class that has three field which are all list?

Comment: @IsaacLem - If you are only going to have those 3 dropdowns, then you will have three fields that contain the selected value, and three collections that contain the dropdownlist data.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly

> Dress table and Customer Table - One to Many relation ship
>
> Body table and Customer table - One to Many relationship
>
> Body table and Dress table - One to Many relationship

If so you'r model design would be like below.

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public List<Body> parts { get; set; }
        public List<Dress> dresses { get; set; }

        public Customer()
        {
            this.parts = new List<Body>();
            this.dresses = new List<Dress>();
        }


    }

    public class Body
    {
        public int PartID { get; set; }
        public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
        public Customer customer { get; set; }
        public Dress dress { get; set; }
    }

    public class Dress
    {
        public int DressID { get; set; }
        public int PartID { get; set; }
        public string LOV { get; set; }

        public Customer customer { get; set; }

        public List<Body> parts { get; set; }

        public Dress()
        {
            this.parts = new List<Body>();
        }
    }
```

**Create View Implementation Example for Dress Model:**

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            List<Body> bodies = new List<Body>()
            { 
                new Body{PartID=1,DefaultValue="Default1"},
                new Body {PartID=2,DefaultValue="Default2"},
                new Body {PartID=3,DefaultValue="Default3"}
            };

            Dress dress = new Dress();
            dress.parts = bodies;

            return View(dress);
        }
```

**View:**

```
@model Mvc4Test.Models.Dress

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Dress</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PartID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">

            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.parts, new SelectList(Model.parts,"PartID","DefaultValue"))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PartID)
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LOV)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LOV)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LOV)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Do you mind to also show how to access the viewmodel at controller

Comment: It seems that those classes you built has no connection with model? Correct me if I'm wrong that a viewModel served as a bridge between model and view?

Comment: There's also something I need to make some correction. Basically there is a dress_ID in customer table is just so that I can tell each customer's dress preference for different body part.

Answer (score 0):

> When you have dozens of distinct values to pass to a view, the same flexibility that allows you to 
>   quickly add a new entry, or rename an existing one, becomes your worst enemy .You are left on your 
>   own to track item names and values; you get no help from Microsoft IntelliSense and compilers .
>   **The only proven way to deal with complexity in software is through appropriate design. So defining an object model for each view helps you track what that view really needs. I suggest you define a 
>   view-model class for each view you add to the application**.

-- "Programming Microsoft ASP.NET MVC" by Dino Esposito

A simple ViewModel might be something like this

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    [Required]  
    public SelectList BarLov1 { get; set; }
    public SelectList BarLov2 { get; set; }
    public SelectList BarLov3 { get; set; }

    // Other data
}
```

Every property in a ViewModel can dress with appropriate `ValidationAttribute`.

You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to automate transfer data from your model to ViewModel and vice versa.

**Update:**

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public SelectList Parts { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public SelectList Dresses { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public string CustomerID { get; set; }

    // Other data
}
```

Comment: Can you please help modify your answer by using the sample data that I've provided? Your answer is too generic that is very hard for me to relate to my situation